# Turn OFF uglify in WebPack 2

Tags: bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs, webpack-2

Is there a way to skip the uglify js plugin from webpack 2 when runs in `--production` mode?

Comment: Can you provide you webpack configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found: 
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/9734d00d8bf0d306654f40e9b34b60db9c7fdda1/bin/config-optimist.js#L47

```js
optimist
  .boolean("p")
  .describe(
    "p", 
    "shortcut for --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV=\"production\""
  )
```

A temp workaround would be run `webpack --define process.env.NODE_ENV=\"production\"`instead of `webpack -p`

Comment: This helped me. I'm using a framework and the default build script command was boiled down to `webpack -p`. So once I removed the `-p`, it stopped minifying.

Comment: You can use any other minifier, look at [**Babili**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babili-webpack-plugin). You can also include `Uglify` manually into webpack plugins.